# How to geometrically show that there are $4$ $S_3$ subgroups in $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

As shown in this [note](http://faculty.smcm.edu/sgoldstine/Math321f09/S4subgroups.pdf), the symmetry group $S_4$ for a cube has 4 subgroups that are isomorphic to $S_3$ for an equilateral triangle. How to geometrically illustrate this fact? Specifically, where are the equilateral triangles embedded in the cube?

---

Related post: [How to geometrically show that there are $3$ $D_4$ subgroups in $S_4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185787/51434)

Comment: There are issues using the cube, since $S_4$ is only its group of *rotational* symmetries. But as the symmetry group of s triangle, $S_3$ naturally includes things we want to be reflections, it's a bit difficult. The 8 vertex figures, equilateral triangles, naturally pair up to give 4 pairs of parallel triangles, so we should see copies of $S_3$ in the full symmetry group of the cube, but I'm not sure there are only 4.

Comment: Set four points out on a square (the squareness is not important but it makes the description easier). Fix a corner of the square. Then just view $S_3$ as the permutations on the three corners you didn't fix. It's "geometric" only in the sense that I described it with a picture :P

Comment: @PatrickStevens, the group of symmetries of a square is *not* $S_3$.

Comment: Note: Four things permuted by the symmetries of a cube are the long diagonals. The two sets of alternate vertices of a cube form the vertices of a pair of tetrahedra. Each long diagonal is perpendicular to a face of each of the tetrahedra (i.e. to two equilateral triangles).

Comment: @MarkBennet Could you please extend this comment into an answer?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I know. I never asserted that it was, and I also said that the square-ness of the square was not important. $S_4$ is the permutations on the corners of the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is functionally equivalent to what Mark Bennet suggests in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2906/mark-bennet) but without reference to tetrahedra (or diagonals of the cube, which is probably a mistake...).

Pick antipodal vertices of the cube, and put points on the adjacent edges, like so:

[image: Antipodal triangles]

Label the vertices of one triangle $1, 2, 3$, and label vertices of the opposite triangle so that points on parallel edges receive the same label (as in the picture). We should probably identify corresponding points (those connected by a line going through the center of the cube) on these triangles, and think of this pair as a single triangle. (It's probably better to play this game on variety of other shapes: a truncated cube, or octahedron, or cuboctahedron, or ...)

Now, rotations around the axis connecting these opposite vertices of the cube cyclically permute the labels, achieving all permutations in $\langle (1\ 2\ 3) \rangle$:

[image: Rotation about axis between opposite vertices]

For the remaining permutations in $S_3$, we need permutations of order $2$. These must be rotations about axes connecting midpoints of opposite edges. Here is the rotation that permutes $2$ and $3$:

[image: Permutation (12)]

It's a bit hard to see, but a $180^\circ$ rotation like this interchanges the two edges parallel to the red edges, and they both contain $1$, so $1$ is fixed. Here the leftmost vertices of each triangle get swapped (likewise with rightmost), so vertices $2$ and $3$ are switched (if we think of our pair of triangles as a single triangle), and we have the permutation $(2\ 3)$.

Here are all of the pairs of edges whose midpoint-connecting-lines are rotation axes that give $2$-cycles (note that none of these edges contain vertices of our triangles):

[image]

So this is one copy of $S_3$, as the symmetry group of "a" triangle, in the group of rotational symmetries of the cube, $S_4$.

The other copies of $S_3$ are obtained similarly, since there are four pairs of antipodal triangles. But to make everything consistent, you have to be careful with the labels for the triangles' vertices:

[image: cube all triangles]

Label each triangle pair with a label from $\{1,2,3,4\}$. To label triangle vertices, use the label of the triangle with a vertex on the same edge (in the image above: our black triangles themselves must be labeled $4$, because its labels are from $\{1,2,3\}$. The red triangles themselves are labeled $1$, so all vertices on the same edge as a vertex of a red triangle get labeled $1$.

In this way, all permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that fix a point (those that belong to some copy of $S_3$ in $S_4$) arise as symmetries of the cube that fix some triangle-pair.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. "But "left" and "right" aren't interchanged, so vertices $2$ and $3$ are (if we think of our pair of triangles as a single triangle), so we have the permutation $(1 \; 2)$.": what are the "left" and "right"? The left triangle and the right triangle? If so, why are they not interchanged? "... so we have the permutation $(1 \; 2)$", is it $(2 \; 3)$ (a typo here)?

Comment: Yes, the $(1\ 2)$ is a typo (I'll fix in a moment, thank you for catching it). By "left" and "right", I just meant that the leftmost vertices of the triangles get swapped (and likewise for right), one of those vertices is labeled $2$, the other $3$, hence the permutation $(2\ 3)$.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible also to view $S_4$ is the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron (i.e., 3-simplex). Then the 4 copies of $S_3$ are just the symmetries of each of the faces of the tetrahedron (fixing the opposite vertex of the tetrahedron).

One can also explain this in terms of the cube by considering the rotations around a main diagonal by multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.  The "triangle" here is the triple of three neighbors of a given vertex (the one on the main diagonal).

Comment: I have thought that the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron is $A_4$ (instead of $S_4$).

Comment: That's only if you use orientation-preserving isometries.  The transposition $(1,2)$ is generated by reflection in the plane passing through $3$, $4$, and the origin.

Comment: I have just checked the wiki article on [tetrahedral symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry) and know about the differences between rotational symmetries and full symmetries. Is your first interpretation in terms of full symmetries and the second one in terms of rotational symmetries? To me, the second one is much more intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for the simplex we use all symmetries and for the cube only the orientation-preserving ones.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your second interpretation. Why are there 4 "triangles"? And why does the rotation around a main diagonal by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ send a "triangle" to itself?

Comment: There are 8 vertices in a cube and therefore precisely 4 main diagonals.  These give rise to 4 "triangles".  Rotation by $2\pi/3$ fixing a vertex preserves the cube and in particular induces a permutation of the three neighbors of the vertex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55283/discussion-between-hengxin-and-mikhail-katz).

Comment: Label the vertices of a triangle with 1, 2, and 3. Now I think I understand how to obtain (1), (1 2 3), and (1 3 2). However, how could I obtain (1 2), (1 3), and (2 3)?

Comment: For the simplex, consider the rotation by 180 degrees around the line passing through the midpoints of a pair of opposite edges of the simplex. For the cube, consider rotation by 180 degrees around a line passing through the centers of a pair of opposite faces.

Comment: "For the cube, consider rotation by 180 degrees around a line passing through the centers of a pair of opposite faces." In my opinion, this will also send one of the three vertices elsewhere while transposing the other two. Did I misunderstand it?